# Lower bound on $L^2$-norm of bounded holomorphic function in the unit disk

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration, holomorphic-functions

I am considering holomorphic functions $g(z)$ on the unit disk such that $|g(z)| \leq M$ for some $M>0$ and also for some real $a < 1$ we have
$$\int_0^a |g(z)|^2 \frac{dz}{1 - z^2} = 1$$
I want to show that for all $d > 0$, there is some $C>0$ such that
$$\int_{z_1}^{z_2} |g(z)|^2 \frac{dz}{1 - z^2} \geq C$$
for any interval $[z_1, z_2] \subseteq [0,a]$ with $z_2 - z_1 \geq d$.

I think I should be using a compactness argument for this. But more importantly, I need a lower bound on $C$ in terms of the other parameters, which might be a lot more difficult.

Thanks :)

Comment: $\displaystyle C = \inf_{x\in (0,1-d)} \int_{x}^{x+d} |g(t)|^2\frac{dt}{1-t^2}$, it can't be zero since $g(z)$ isn't identically zero

Comment: You should explain your precise problem (and your particular $g(z)$)

Comment: @user1952009 as stated in the question I am considering the entire family of functions that satisfy the above properties, and the bound will be universal.

Comment: Try with the simplest families : $g(z) = a$ or $g(z) = a+bz$ or $g(z) = (a+bz)(1-z^2)^{1/2}$ you'll see there is no non-trivial bound in general

Comment: @user1952009 I really have no idea what you are saying.